# Notification when c-style stdout / stderr written to?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a class that catches all console output and dumps it into one log. I need this because my program uses many 3rd party libraries that I cannot change. Useful information from these libraries is printed to the console in a handful of ways. I know about replacing the `cout`/`cerr` with a custom stream buffer using `rdbuf`. I don't need help with that. I also know about creating a pipe to capture c-style output, e.g. `fprintf( stdout, "Hello, world!" )`. However, unlike a custom stream buffer where I can handle output as it comes in, the c-style output is now stuck in this pipe and I have to periodically flush everything and read from it. I would much rather get a notification or install a callback to handle pipe input as it happens.

Qt is in the mix here, too. I've been playing with the `QSocketNotifier` class, but it doesn't seem to be working the pipe read or write file descriptors.

Suggestions?

Comment: C++ And C Are not the same thing

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do what you want.

Comment: This _screams_ X-Y problem.

Comment: Just have a thread blocked on the pipe.

Comment: Which operating system(s) do you need this to work on?

Comment: @hyde Windows and Linux.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yep, that's an idea.

Comment: You can't do what you want. You're trying to apply asynchronicity to a level of programming that isn't built for asynchronous operations. I guarantee you this is just a matter of being lazy with your information processing. Are you trying to capture what they are outputting? There is a clear way to do that. Are you trying to get something meaningful from their outputs? 1) Don't do that, 2) There is almost always a way to get that information without string munging. I could go on, but you get the idea.

Comment: A general rule of thumb: if there isn't a widespread way of doing something _with file descriptors/pipes specifically_, there's probably not a way, period. They have been around for decades. Plus, your question is incredibly vague, so even getting a clear picture as to what you're trying to do is nearly impossible.

Comment: @Qix "You're trying to apply asynchronicity to a level of programming that isn't built for asynchronous operations." Correct. The documentation for QSocketNotifier and examples I've looked at would seem to imply that it would work, but it doesn't seem to like pipe file descriptors. I'm asking for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Qix Did you downvote my question? You're hilarious. There's nothing vague about my question at all. It's very specific actually. David Schwartz's suggestion works. As does using a simple QTimer callback, but that's pretty ugly. I'm sorry you got upset and were unable to help.

Comment: @Brock I look at hundreds of questions a day, I hold no emotional attachment to your opinions. This question has 4 close votes already. You're welcome to [take it to meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you're so inclined.

Comment: @Qix "Are you trying to capture what they are outputting?" Yes. "There is a clear way to do that." Well, what is that? "Are you trying to get something meaningful from their outputs?" Nope, just capture it, combine it with all other console output, and dump it to one log file. Anyways, as you can see below, kfsone provided a very helpful answer instead of just tearing down my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> output is now stuck in this pipe and I have to periodically flush everything and read from it. I would much rather get a notification or install a callback to handle pipe input as it happens.

It's unclear what "everything" is or why you would need to do more than flush specific file streams, but this sounds like you are referring to the fact that these streams are buffered so the pipes you have connected them to aren't written to until flush conditions are met or `flush()` is executed.

Further, we don't know whether you are manipulating the layer 3 file streams or the layer 2 file descriptors. We don't know whether you've disabled synchronization between C++ streams and layer 3 streams.

All that said, it is possible to disable the C layer 3 buffering with

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This means you won't have to `flush()` any more for, say, `fprintf()` calls to be written to the pipes.

For that, you can set up a poll/select call to check for data on the pipes or you can simply have threads performing blocking reads from them and transfer the data someplace else.

Comment: Disabling C layer 3 buffering with setvbuf on stdout/stderr and redirected to the pipe write-end using dup and dup2 with blocking reads on the pipe read-end in a separate thread worked beautifully. Thank-you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, we use to redirect the standard streams:

```
freopen (outfile, "a", stdout);
freopen (outfile, "a", stderr);
```

I don't believe there's any way to get a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had previously found that solution, but it fails to do what I need. Perhaps, I should have been more specific in my question: I was looking for a way to combine all console messages into one log file. Capturing stdout/stderr was the last piece of that puzzle.